# access UIView objects in array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, addsubview

i´ve defined an array which contents 4 UIView objects which were already defined

```
NSArray *districtArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, nil];
```

now i´d like to add a subview to an UIView accessing the array via an index. i can´t figure out how i have to write that

it should be something like that

```
[districtArray[0] addSubview:poiObject];
```

could anybody give me a hint about the syntax?

thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the *n*-th object in an NSArray, use

```
[array objectAtIndex:n]
```

e.g.

```
[[districtArray objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:poiObject];
```

---

**Edit**: Starting from Xcode 4.4 (2012 Jul) OP's syntax *is* supported, i.e.

```
[districtArray[0] addSubview:poiObject];
```

does work as expected. This is known as [object subscripting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#object-subscripting).

Comment: Can you make this with for loop ? e.g: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:view1, view2, view3, view4, view500] ; ?

Comment: @YumYumYum Use an `NSMutableArray` and `appendObject:` ([Please create a question post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).)